# Javascript change width of div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to do three things `onclick`:

1. have element with `id="notes_content"` change `display:none` to `display: block`
2. have element with `id="oct"` change `width = "1190px"` to `width = "550px"`
3. have elements with `class="oct_days"` change `width = "168px"` to `width = "73px"`

Fiddle of full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ascottz/jX3wh/

The first two happen, but the third does not. I suspect it is a syntax error, but can't catch it myself.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array. You haven't specified which index you want to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of dom elements, it is not a single instance. You must loop over the array and style each element.

Have a look at the updated fiddle.

```
for( var i = 0; i < days.length; i++ ){
    days[i].style.width = "73px";        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jX3wh/4/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns somewhat an array of elements, so you cannot simply refer to it as a DOM element in hope that it will work as you refer to each element of the collection (that is possible in jQuery, btw), so you have to use the foreach loop (doesn't matter how are you gonna achieve this -- via simple `for()`, or `for(x in y)`, or any other way).

I usually use `Array.forEach` function, but the specific type of an array returned by the `document.getElementsByClassName` does not have such function in prototype, so you have to use `[].forEach.call(inWhat,function(what){})` syntax, or fallback to `for(...)` syntax.

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/jX3wh/1/
Dunno if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also, what the f is this???

```
<div onclick="javascript:showDiv();" class="oct_days">
```

I am really very surprised this works. You should use `onclick="showDiv()"` instead, I think.

Somebody, please, tell me how does it work!

Comment: you can run that code from within a script tag too. It's not necessary or recommend but it's not wrong...

Comment: I thought when the `click` event fires, the string set by the `onclick` attribute in the HTML tag executes by the script engine, and, of course, `javascript:showDiv()` code executed by the JS scripting engine should throw a syntax error! Why does it work?