# Multiple HTML elements with same ID causing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently running into a problem where inside my HTML document, I have a carousel, and inside each slide a new button shows up, all doing the same thing. Each one of these buttons is a navbar-toggle button, which displays a navbar if it is pressed.

I problem I'm having is that in the code I was given, it only accounts for one of these buttons to work, the first one to load, as it declares the variable by `var showRightPush = document.getElementByID`. The problem is that I want to be able to click this button on every slide.

Below is my code, the old code, as well as the code in the full context.
Thanks.

**MY CODE**

```
<script>
  var menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
    showRightPush = document.getElementsByClassName( 'navbar-toggle' ),
    body = document.body;


  showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'navbar-toggle' );
  };


</script>
```

**OLD CODE**

```
<script>
  var menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
    showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
    body = document.body;


  showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
  };


</script>
```

**FULL CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Sidebar core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

<body class="cbp-spmenu-push">

      <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
        <h3><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h3>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Submit</a>
        <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
        <a href="#">Follow</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>


      <?php 
     $number = 0; 
     query_posts(array('post_type' => 'facts')); 
     if(have_posts()):  
    ?>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ol>

      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-top navbar-inverse visible-xs <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {echo $category->slug;} ?>" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" id="showRightPush" class="btn btn-default navbar-toggle" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/brains.png" alt=""> </a>
            </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
          </div> <!-- end container -->
          </nav> <!-- end navbar -->

          <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse visible-xs bottom-nav-colour" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header text-center">
                <ul class="bottom-directions">
                  <li><a href="#myCarousel" class="bottom-arrow-nav" data-slide="prev"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/prev.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#myCarousel" class="bottom-arrow-nav" data-slide="random"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/random.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#myCarousel" class="bottom-arrow-nav no-border-right" data-slide="next"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/next.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <ul>
              </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
          </nav> <!-- end navbar -->

          <div class="fact-number-container <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {echo $category->slug;} ?>">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="fact-header">
                <h3>/Fact <span class="fact-number"><?php echo(types_render_field("fact-number", array())); ?></span></h3>
              </div> <!-- end fact-header -->
            </div> <!-- end container -->
          </div> <!-- end fact-number-container -->

          <div class="fact-text-container">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="fact-text">
                <p><?php echo(types_render_field("fact-text", array())); ?></p>
              </div> <!-- end fact-text -->
            </div> <!-- end container --> 
          </div> <!-- end fact-text-container -->

          <div class="tweet-this-container">
            <div class="container">
              <a href="#"> 
                <div class="tweet-this ">
                  <p><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="">Share this fact like a champ</p>
                </div> <!-- end tweet-this -->
              </a> 
            </div> <!-- end container -->
          </div> <!-- end tweet-this-container -->
        </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- Make sure to add jQuery - download the most recent version at http://jquery.com/ -->
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/gyv3ykj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

    <script>
      var menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        showRightPush = document.getElementsByClassName( 'navbar-toggle' ),
        body = document.body;


      showRightPush.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
        classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
        disableOther( 'navbar-toggle' );
      };


    </script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
      $(".carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");  
    });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How much of this code/html can you change? it would be best to move away from id's when you have something that isn't unique.

Comment: *"Multiple HTML elements with same ID causing errors"*, well yes. That's invalid HTML for a start.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to change the code for it to call on classes, but it isn't working. That's the whole reason I made this question.

Comment: Then you should start by renaming the topic, considering you made the appropriate changes.

Comment: IF you are using jQuery you can do away with $('.class-name')

Comment: IDs are unique and can only be specified for one element on a page. Use Classes

Answer (score 0):

```
  showRightPush = document.getElementsByClassName( 'navbar-toggle' ),

  showRightPush.onclick = function() {
      /* ... */
  };
```

Oh god, that **won't work**!
I've just answered this question: [Javascript change width of div onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283158/javascript-change-width-of-div-onclick/19283372)

And will just copypaste my answer:

> `document.getElementsByClassName` returns somewhat an array of
>   elements, so you cannot simply refer to it as a DOM element in hope
>   that it will work as you refer to each element of the collection (that
>   is possible in jQuery, btw), so you have to use the foreach loop
>   (doesn't matter how are you gonna achieve this -- via simple `for()`,
>   or `for(x in y)`, or any other way).
>
> I usually use `Array.forEach` function, but the specific type of an
>   array returned by the `document.getElementsByClassName` does not have
>   such function in prototype, so you have to use
>   `[].forEach.call(inWhat,function(what){})` syntax, or fallback to
>   `for(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be aware that the `getElementsByClassName` method will only work for versions of Internet Explorer from 9 and up. You can use a polyfill like [this one](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607) to enable the functionality in older browsers, or use some other method to find the elements with the correct class name. Having said that, you'll have to iterate over the buttons and bind the click event for each of them.

```
var showRightPush = document.getElementsByClassName( 'navbar-toggle' );
for (var i = 0; i < showRightPush.length; i++) {
    showRightPush[i].onclick = function() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean, it is not very clear. But as far as I understand you should do something like this (I am using `jQuery` since you tagged it)

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
    ...some events
    var class_header = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var index = $('.'+class_header).indexOf($(this).parent());
    $('.'+class_header).eq(index+1).append('/*whatever you want, here your button */'); 
  };
```